# How to build a listview that can slide both vertically and horizontally

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i am using flutter to develop a application,now i need a listview which can slide both vertically and horizontally,any suggestions? I need to show some data like datatable,but while scrolling vertically the first row(column name) needs to be fixed at the top,while scrolling horizontally the first column(row name) needs to be fixed at the left,i don't know what to do,please help me,thanks very much!

Comment: What did you tried so far? can you show us your code?

Comment: According to what I understood, You can use ListView with scrolldirection set to horizontally inside another ListView with default(vertical) direction.

Comment: Thanks,and i just tried it,in a horizontally listview just have one listview can scroll vertically,but in my case,the horizontally listview's width is fixed!but how to fixed the first row while scrolling vertically and fixed the first column while scrolling horizontally?

Comment: You can use column and row for that

Comment: I think i can use a vertically listview and a horizontally listview,because the core data listview is overflow the screen,thanks very much for your help!